# hasmany in express js not working with sequelize

Tags: express

I have created models Skills and Members

Member Table:

```
id  username    password    created
1   gagandeep   99703dd91da5b0cabf496d49af0ab03c2dfe7788    2017-08-14 05:59:46
```

Skills Table:

```
id  member_id   skill
1   1   programming
2   1   music
```

Code:

Model

```
var Member=Seq.define('members',{}, {});
var Skills=Seq.define('skills',{}, {});
Member.hasMany(Skills,{as: 'skills', through: 'skills', foreignKey:'member_id'});
```

Call:

```
router.route('/test').get(function(req, resp){
    Member.findAll({include: [{model: Skills}]},{
            raw:true
        }).success(onSuccess).error(onError);

        function onSuccess(data){
            resp.json(data);
        }

        function onError(data){
            resp.json(data);
        }
});
```

But Node js showing error as below:

Error: skills is not associated to members! at DAOFactory.validateIncludedElement (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dao-factory.js:1476:13) at DAOFactory.validateIncludedElements (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dao-factory.js:1388:59) at DAOFactory.module.exports.DAOFactory.findAll (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dao-factory.js:458:34) at Object.handle (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\demo.js:72:9) at next_layer (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:103:13) at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:107:5) at C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:195:24 at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:251:12) at next (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:189:19) at next (C:\Users\promatics\Desktop\netpar\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:38)

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need that `through` statement.  You only use `through` when you have an association between two tables through a junction table.  What I would do here is something like...

```
var Member = Seq.define('members', {
  // Some attributes...
});

var Skills = Seq.define('skills', {
  // Some attributes...
});

Member.hasMany(Skills, {
  as: 'skills', 
  // Remove `through`!
  foreignKey: 'member_id'
});

// Want to query for all members with the skills joined?
Member.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Skills,
    as: 'skills'
  }
});
```

That should get you the results you are looking for.  Each `member` object will have reference to an inner `skills` key, which will be an array of skills associated to the user.

Good luck :)

Comment: Which version of Sequelize are you using?  3.x.x, 4.x.x?

Comment: I am using version sequelize@~1.7.0